# Declaration of ... must be compatible with

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

I have this module enabled, and when I try to run setup:di:compile I get this error

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Mirasvit\Helpdesk\Ui\Component\DataProvider\FulltextFilter::apply() must be compatible with Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterApplierInterface::apply(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection, Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter) in /home/magento2/public_html/app/code/Mirasvit/Helpdesk/Ui/Component/DataProvider/FulltextFilter.php on line 27
```

This is the original Magento 2 class

```
namespace Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;


interface FilterApplierInterface
{
    public function apply(AbstractDb $collection, \Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filters);
}
```

And this is the extended class in module

```
namespace Mirasvit\Helpdesk\Ui\Component\DataProvider;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb as DbCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;


class FulltextFilter implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterApplierInterface
{

    protected function getFulltextIndexColumns(DbCollection $collection, $indexTable)
    {
        $indexes = $collection->getConnection()->getIndexList($indexTable);
        foreach ($indexes as $index) {
            if (strtoupper($index['INDEX_TYPE']) == 'FULLTEXT') {
                return $index['COLUMNS_LIST'];
            }
        }

        return [];
    }

    public function apply(DbCollection $collection, Filter $filter)
    {
        $columns = $this->getFulltextIndexColumns($collection, $collection->getMainTable());
        if (!$columns) {
            return;
        }
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->where(
                'MATCH('.implode(',', $columns).') AGAINST(?)',
                $filter->getValue()
            );
    }
}
```

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ryan H, Thank you for your answer, it helped me to find out the real issue,

I had Magento 2.0.7 code base on my development and Magento 2.1 on my server, so the specific core Magento file looked differnt

```
namespace Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider;

    use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
    use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;

    interface FilterApplierInterface
    {
        public function apply(Collection $collection, Filter $filter);
    }
```

This is how it looked like on Magento 2.1, so I changed my module code to be look like this

```
public function apply(\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection, \Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
{
        $columns = $this->getFulltextIndexColumns($collection, $collection->getMainTable());
        if (!$columns) {
            return;
        }
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->where(
                'MATCH('.implode(',', $columns).') AGAINST(?)',
                $filter->getValue()
            );
}
```

and it solved the problem for me.